# My IF condition isn't working

Tags: php, if-statement, ssh

I have a problem. Here is my code:

```
$resultado=$ssh->exec('[ -d /usr/share/servermanager/backups/  ] && echo "found" || echo "not_found" '); 
        //die ($resultado);
            if($resultado == "found"){
                $alert_inst='<span class="label label-success mr10 mt10" >Instalado</span>';
            }else{
                $alert_inst='<span class="label label-danger mr10 mt10" >Não instalado</span>';   
            }
```

When I uncomment my `die()`, it prints out:

```
found
```

But the if statement doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: What does `var_dump($resultado);` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably some additional whitespace before or after `found` in the string returned from `$ssh->exec`. Use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on your `$resultado` variable before comparing it.

#### Example:

```
if(trim($resultado) == "found"){
```